# I want add my simples list in list of comprehension in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have two lists of 24 values and I would like to create a list which could be seen as a 24x2 matrix where the first column is my the values of my first list and the other column is the values of my second list.

Here are my two lists:

```py
q = [6.0, 5.75, 5.5, 5.25, 5.0, 4.75, 4.5, 4.25, 4.0, 3.75, 3.5, 3.25, 3.0, 2.75, 2.5, 2.25, 2.0, 1.75, 1.5, 1.25, 1.0, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25]
t = [0.38, 0.51, 0.71, 1.09, 2.0, 5.68, 0.31, 0.32, 0.34, 0.35, 0.36, 0.38, 0.4, 0.42, 0.44, 0.48, 0.51, 0.56, 0.63, 0.74, 1.41, 2.17, 3.97, 11.36]
```

Comment: SO isn't a code-writing service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you looked into how to use the `zip` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zip()` function like this

```py
q = [6.0, 5.75, 5.5, 5.25, 5.0, 4.75, 4.5, 4.25, 4.0, 3.75, 3.5, 3.25, 3.0, 2.75, 2.5, 2.25, 2.0, 1.75, 1.5, 1.25, 1.0, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25]
t = [0.38, 0.51, 0.71, 1.09, 2.0, 5.68, 0.31, 0.32, 0.34, 0.35, 0.36, 0.38, 0.4, 0.42, 0.44, 0.48, 0.51, 0.56, 0.63, 0.74, 1.41, 2.17, 3.97, 11.36]

L1 = list(zip(q, t))

res = []

for i, j in L1:
    res.append(i)
    res.append(j)

print(res)
```

Comment: so  when i put them like a said ?

Comment: Not getting you

Comment: i tried to put that list in the format : print('{0:>12}{1:>12}'.format(res)). i want to put the first index in the first colum and the sencond on second colum

Comment: i want my lists in comprehension list so i could put them  in table

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you just need to [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) your two lists:

```py
myList = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
myOtherList = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]

# Iterator of tuples
zip(myList, myOtherList)

# List of tuples
list(zip(myList, myOtherList))
```

You will get this result: `[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'e'), (5, 'f')]`.

If you need another structure, you could use comprehension:

```py
length = min(len(myList), len(myOtherList))

# List of list
[[myList[i], myOtherList[i]] for i in range(length)] 

# Dict
{myList[i]: myOtherList[i] for i in range(length)}
```

Comment: but i want my list being floats and not string

Comment: If you replace the examples list I used in my response by yours you will have floats instead. I only showed you an EXAMPLE, feel free to adapt it to your code.

Comment: ok thanks. now if i want to format that zip. what i do?                                                      exemple:                                                                                                                                  0 a                                                                                                                                            1 b    like that what i need to do?

Comment: `myList` and `myOtherList` were just examples... Just use your list `q` and `t` instead.

Comment: @Programmin-in-Python i am using python3